# Linux datetime event

Tags: linux, datetime, events

I'm looking for an event usable in C language that can trigger on a datetime.
I want my program to idle and wake up when a specific datetime is reached, i can't find any documentation of this type of features, is anything existing for this purpose ?

thanks

Comment: Use the `sleep()` function.

Comment: You need to calculate the number of seconds from now to the datetime.

Comment: I'm not a big fan of using sleep() for this purpose, i want the system to react on a particular datetime not a duration, one reason is that i'm french and we switch hour two times a year and don't really want to add condition to test this (if it is possible)

Comment: The function for converting a datetime to a timestamp takes the time switch into account.

Comment: Any reason you're not using something like `cron` or `batch` to run a program at a specific time?

Comment: I don't use cron because i have to retreive datetime from a file and datetime can be changed by user, i feel this easier to do with C/Cpp than cron